# SQL Interpolation from Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

this is the code from Ruby on Rails Tutorial by MH:

```
def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
    Micropost.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
end
```

Is this SQL safe? Because many people told me never use interpolation but use escaped code ever (with ? in this case). So is this code safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.

There is no interpolation, in fact: the whole query could be written as

```
Micropost.where("user_id IN (
     SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
      WHERE  follower_id = :user_id)
   OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
```

but for the sake of clarity, the first query was extracted into it’s own variable.

Interpolation must be avoided when the interpolated string comes from the outside. This string is constructed by you, right here, hence there is no risk of SQL injection or like.

---

**Examples**

*safe, `id` is determined:*

```
id = 42
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = #{id}"
```

*unsafe, `params[:id]` comes from the outside and might be dangerous:*

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = #{params[:id]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is safe because the string interpolation itself is not the issue. It only leads to a security vulnerability if you do not control the text that gets interpolated into the query.

In your example, the string `following_ids` that is inserted is not an unknown user input but a fixed SQL subquery. This cannot lead to a security issue.

But I agree that this is still not a good example and should probably be refactored to use scopes and Rails query syntax.